# Fetch data.json redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to fetch my data from the data.json file. The file is located locally. This is my file structure
Test

```
-data
--data.json
-testActions.js
-testActionTypes.js
-testReducer.js
```

In `testActions.js`  i have

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    import * as actionTypes from './testActionTypes';
    import jsonData from './data/data';

  const fetchQuestionsStart = () => ({
      type: actionTypes.FETCH_QUESTIONS_START,
    });

    const fetchQuestionsSucces = (data) => ({
      type: actionTypes.FETCH_QUESTIONS_SUCCESS,
      data,
    });

    const fetchQuestionsError = (error) => ({
      type: actionTypes.FETCH_QUESTIONS_FAIL,
      error,
    });

    const fetchQuestions = () => (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(fetchQuestionsStart());
      return axios.get(jsonData)
        .then((res) => dispatch(fetchQuestionsSucces(res.data)))
        .catch((err) => dispatch(fetchQuestionsError(err.response.data)));
    };
```

In console  I have this: `http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 500 (Internal Server Error)`

how to fetch data by redux?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a GET call using axios you must provide the URL of the json file
eg.

```
const fetchQuestions = () => (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(fetchQuestionsStart());
      return axios.get('data/data.json')
        .then((res) => dispatch(fetchQuestionsSucces(res.data)))
        .catch((err) => dispatch(fetchQuestionsError(err.response.data)));
    };
```

And if you are running it locally and the port is 3000 the url will internally resolve into http://localost:3000/data/data.json

```
axios("http://localost:3000/data/data.json")
```